# .jar file not executing when executed from CMD prompt

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar

So I was following the instructions from my assignment on creating my Maven project and I followed them exactly but I am getting hung up on the last part. Here are the instructions below

*Copy the JAR file (helloworld.jar) to the Desktop. Open a terminal window and run the JAR
application by using the following command. NOTE: the path to the Java application can
be found by going to the Spring Tool Suite IDE Properties, selecting Java > Installed
JREs, copying the path listed under the JRE 15.0, and appending /bin to that path. Note,
that if there are any spaces in the directory path then the Java command including the
path should be entirely enclosed in double quotes.
Mac: [PATH to Java 15 JRE Install]/bin/java -jar helloworld.jar
Windows: [PATH to Java 15 JRE Install]\bin\java.exe -jar helloworld.jar
8. Open a browser and go to localhost:8080. The content of the index.html page should be
displayed. Take a screenshot.*

I know the file should work because the program executes in Eclipse. It is a Spring Boot project using Maven.

When I change my working directory to the desktop and run `java -jar topic1-1.jar` it executes for about a couple seconds and then it prompts for another command `C:\>` . I tried going to my local host as well and it isn't working.

Is there any logging I can set up to get it to throw an error for me?
How do I make sure my path is set up right? Am I in the right working directory or do I need to be in ``\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin``` then execute my command? because when I execute it from that directory it is unable to access the file.... because it is on the desktop.

Console output when I run in Eclipse

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.1.1)[0;39m

[2m2023-06-29T07:18:56.615-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.example.demo.Topic11Application     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Topic11Application using Java 18.0.2.1 with PID 18568 (C:\Users\mitch\git\topic1-1\target\classes started by mitch in C:\Users\mitch\git\topic1-1)
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:56.620-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.example.demo.Topic11Application     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:56.694-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:56.694-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:57.776-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:57.790-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:57.790-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.10]
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:57.882-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:57.883-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1187 ms
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:58.108-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:58.205-05:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false)
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:58.259-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m LiveReload server is running on port 35729
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:58.299-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2023-06-29T07:18:58.310-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.example.demo.Topic11Application     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started Topic11Application in 2.11 seconds (process running for 2.9)
[2m2023-06-29T07:19:33.746-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2023-06-29T07:19:33.747-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2023-06-29T07:19:33.749-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18568[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

output from cmd prompt

[image]

In the cmd prompt, it goes to the blank lines for a couple of seconds and then is done. The program should continue to run because when I run it in Eclipse as a Spring Boot App it continues to run until I terminate it. While running in Eclipse I can go to my localhost:8080 and it shows my webpage. In the cmd prompt, it does not.

Output when I changed my directory to Desktop and ran it. Again same thing, runs for a couple seconds and goes to next line.

[image]

Command to run suggested by @g00se

```
C:\>java -jar C:\Users\mitch\OneDrive\Desktop\topic1-1.jar
```

[image]

Code from project

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Topic11Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Topic11Application.class, args);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: If it executes for a couple of seconds without printing an error message, that's what your application is doing: nothing to do with the command.

Comment: *I know the file should work because the program executes in Eclipse. It is a Spring Boot project using Maven.* And what output do you see in the Eclipse console?

Comment: Please show the output while you tried to start it...

Comment: @g00se and I have added what you asked for.

Comment: @khmarbaise I have added what you asked for.

Comment: Very confusing cmd.exe stuff. Exactly what directory is that jar in?

Comment: If it's in the Desktop directory per the instructions, the command should be `java -jar C:\Users\mitch\Desktop\topic1-1.jar`

Comment: Well the instructions wanted me to copy and paste the .jar file from the target folder in my project onto my desktop. I have also changed my directory to the Desktop and it still doesn't work I get the same results

Comment: Open a new cmd.exe. Paste the command I gave you into it and hit return. Copy ALL of the text out of that window and paste it into your question *formatted as code*

Comment: Probably because it's a Spring app. You want instead `java -cp C:\Users\mitch\Desktop\topic1-1.jar fully.qualified.package.Application` Obviously you need to use the name of your actual Spring app class

Comment: I added that info @g00se

Comment: See my comment above. And stop changing directories - it's pointless ;)

Comment: Roger that. So for needing the name of my Spring app class what would that be exactly? I'll paste the code from my project above.

Comment: Also please stop posting pictures. cmd.exe is a *text* interface so post the *text* from it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254302/discussion-between-mitchell-and-g00se).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is that your CMD is not pointing to your Desktop.
A terminal pointing to Desktop should look like this:

[image]

Yours, is pointing to the root of C filesystem
To change your working directory to Desktop, type:

```
cd Desktop
```

Comment: I have done that and I get the same results.